# Scrapy returns Crawled (406) error / problem scraping weekly circulars

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I wanted to scrape Rite Aid's weekly circular and through the Network tab, I found the json link filled with what I needed (brand name, price, discount). From scraping past json projects, I created this on scrapy

```
class RiteAidSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'riteaid'
    start_urls = ['https://weeklyad.info.riteaid.com/flyer_data/3444750?locale=en-US']

def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    for items in data:
        item_name = items['display_name']
        sales_price = items['current_price']
        pre_price = items['pre_price_text']
        yield {
            'store': 'rite aid',
            'name': item_name,
            'discount': pre_price,
            'sales_price': sales_price,
        }
```

but when I run the program, I get "Scrapy Crawled (406) HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed."

One thing that I find weird is when I enter the start_url in my browser, the json doesn't appear. From past scraping projects, whenever I put the json link in my browser, I could still see the json data, but not for this. I don't understand why it won't show up.

Can anyone point me in the right direction and tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I have to learn in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (HTTP) 406 Not Acceptable ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406)) client error response code indicates that the server cannot produce a response matching the list of acceptable values defined in the request's proactive content negotiation headers, and that the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.

In my opinion the server you're trying to communicate has some `validations / verifications` to not return data to web crawlers.

If it worked before and now it is not, maybe it is a protection put to work only now.
If you would like to try to avoid that problem, maybe you can change some 'default' settings from your script.

You can change the settings.py file in you current project, look up for that information here and change according to a current web browser installed in your machine.

Access the developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) `network tab`, do a navigation in site, copy information from some request in that domain.

***settings.py***

```
USER_AGENT = '' #copy user-agent from browser

# Override the default request headers:
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
  'Accept': '', #copy this info from browser
  'Accept-Language': '', #copy this info from browser
}
```

Here is a [good tutorial](http://sangaline.com/post/advanced-web-scraping-tutorial/) (2017) that explains in detail how can you handle navigation errors, old but you can get the main idea. This tutorial is also linked in scrapy web site `resources` section.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I added the DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS and it is now working. I bookmarked your tutorial link for future reference. Thank you so much for the answer!