# python css selector pulling none type

Tags: python, web-scraping, css-selectors, nonetype

I keep getting a return none type for this while trying to pull the title why?
I've been playing with it all day and looking up many different things still nothing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
urlz = "http://www.weedmaps.com/search?entryType=home%20page%20product%20card&filter%5BboundingRadius%5D=120mi&page=1"
def get_page_link(url):
    baseurl = "https://weedmaps.com"
    r = requests.get(url)
    sp = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')
    links = sp.select("#menu-tab-wrapper div.styles__NameRatingWrap-j5iyiv-15.eaLQmf > a:nth-child(2)")
                       #menu-tab-wrapper > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div.styles__NameRatingWrap-j5iyiv-15.eaLQmf > a:nth-child(2)
    return [baseurl + link.attrs['href'] for link in links]
    #print (len(links))
    

def product_data(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    sp = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')
    product={
         'Title: ': sp.select_one("#content > div.content-wrapper__ContentWrapper-ljfebg-0.efqrNq > div > div > div.src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0.src__Flex-sc-1sbtrzs-1.bQaUiS.eSfsMV > div.src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0.jvkycj > div > h1 ")
        #'Brand': sp.select_one("div.styled-components__ProductCategoryBrand-sc-1fbw3xt-6 a").text
        #'Price': sp.select_one("div.styled-components__Price-sc-1fbw3xt-15 ").text
        #'Distance': sp.select_one("div.styled-components__FromListing-sc-1fbw3xt-20 span").text
        #'Pick_up_location': sp.select_one("div.styled-components__FromListing-sc-1fbw3xt-20 span").text
        #'Obj_type': sp.select_one("div.styled-components__ProductCategoryBrand-sc-1fbw3xt-6").text
                 }    
    return(product)
      
product_data("https://weedmaps.com/brands/stiiizy/products/stiiizy-battery-starter-kit?filter%5BanyWeights%5D%5Bunit%5D%5B0%5D=1&filter%5BboundingRadius%5D=120mi&boost%5Blisting_wmid%5D=587311662&origin=search")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "https://weedmaps.com/brands/stiiizy/products/stiiizy-battery-starter-kit?filter%5BanyWeights%5D%5Bunit%5D%5B0%5D=1&filter%5BboundingRadius%5D=120mi&boost%5Blisting_wmid%5D=587311662&origin=search"
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> sp = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')
>>> sp.prettify()
'<html>\n <body>\n  <p>\n   406 Not Acceptable\n  </p>\n </body>\n</html>'
>>> print(r.text)
406 Not Acceptable
```

This is the result I got. Seems the server has a kind of anti-crawler, or you need extra verification.

It is obvious you cannot get the element out of where it doesn't even exist.

I suppose you need to change the crawler.

Thanks for reading.

Here is a link that might be helpful.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928421/scrapy-returns-crawled-406-error-problem-scraping-weekly-circulars)